# What does でポン mean?

Tags: meaning, onomatopoeia

There are several manga, games, websites etc in Japan with the でポン in the title, such as ミルモでポン, パネルでポン, ヨシりんでポン, 住所でポン.

I think I can infer it is some sort of onomatopoeia but I don't understand the meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ポン is an onomatopoeia which represents a tiny explosive sound, like "Pop!" or "Pong!". で is technically a method/means/situation marker here (e.g., "With 住所, something pops").

What ポン represents depends on the title.

- 住所でポン: ポン describes how a phone number "pops" up.
- パネルでポン: ポン describes how the matched panels "pop".
- ミルモでポン: (I don't know the story, but ポン is a common sound of a magic spell.)
- ヨシりんでポン: ( Maybe just a parody of other ～でポン, or this may describe the book is like a toy box from which random contents pop up.)